Has anyone used SSIS to extract data from a Power BI report?
I am trying to use SSIS to extract data from a Power BI Report. I can explore the data fine from DAX Studio, and i know the Database i need to connect to. However, using SSMS, it connects to the Power BI report, but does not show the databases underneath it. If i try to configure SSIS connection to the Power BI report, setting the intial catalog as the DB i need to query, it fails with an Error initializing provider.
I want to connect to the Power BI report using SSIS, and use DAX Queries to extract data. I want to use For Loops to break down a large DAX query and get the data from Power BI.
